# "How to Resolve 'Command Failed' Error (Exit Code: 127) in

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, render.com

error /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/msnodesqlv8: Command failed.
Exit code: 127
Command: prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
Arguments:
Directory: /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/msnodesqlv8
Output:
/bin/sh: 1: node-gyp: not found
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
==> Build failed

What specific error did you encounter during the activation of the web service in the render, and how can the issue with the "/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/msnodesqlv8: Command failed. Exit code: 127" error be resolved, especially considering the "node-gyp: not found" message?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.